# Правильная архитектура приложения

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, архитектура, asp.net-web-api

Всем привет! Занимаюсь разработкой бека на asp.net. Команда маленькая, и с архитектурой приходится разбираться самому. Сейчас в качестве шаблона использую чистую архитектуру от https://github.com/ivanpaulovich/clean-architecture-manga. Дополнительно пытаюсь использовать CQRS. Добавил dto в Application слой и запрашиваю данные, не используя доменные сущности.
Смотрел другие подходы и везде используют медиатор. Я, получается, использую порты адаптеры. Какое преимущество даёт использование медиатора по сравнению с моим примером(шаблоном)?

Comment: Не бывает стандартной идеальной архитектуры. Кому-то полноценная доменная модель нужна, а кому-то и даппер в контроллерах ок. Паттерны - это типовые решения типовых проблем. Если у вас на проекте конкретная проблема есть - решайте не. Если нет - то нет :)

Comment: Плюс вопросу за интересный репозиторий! Но Ваш вопрос пока еще ждет своего ответа...